# How to make 1 button with changing ids do different things?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that when pressed besides doing something it changes its own id so when pressed again it does something different as if it is a different button. The problem is that after changing the id for the first time the prev button click function throws an error because the id doesn't exist anymore.

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    //do something
    document.getElementById("#button1").id = "button2";
});

$("#button2").click(function() {
    //do something different
    document.getElementById("#button2").id = "button1";
});
```

Comment: You should probably be changing something different than the ID... like a data- attribute or a class. Then you can base your behavior off of the data- attribute or whether a class exists.

Comment: i really suggest you just show and hide separate buttons, that way you dont have to complicate your life with jquery function bindings management

Comment: I'd change the approach. Something like suggested in comments above, or remove the first event listener (in the first event handler), and add a new-one.

Comment: I would recommend what the others have suggested, but if you have to, you can use jquery 'on' http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using jQuery on, but like mentioned in comments, this might be a sign you need to change your approach. However, if you must do it this way, here is a solution using jQuery's 'on'.

http://jsfiddle.net/WetNoodles/ab5yn7eL/

```
$('#outerContainer').on('click', '#button1', function () {
    alert('button 1 clicked!');
    $(this).attr('id', 'button2');
});

$('#outerContainer').on('click', '#button2', function () {
    alert('button 2 clicked!');
    $(this).attr('id', 'button1');
});
```

Some additional notes - If you take **smerny's** approach, you will still need to use the 'on' function in order to bind events to changing attributes unless you have the onclick attribute set directly on the html tag. **Kristian's** approach would let you use the click functions like you are currently using.

Comment: Excelent, thank you for the answer and the full example at jsfiddle.

Comment: Noodles, delegation is not needed for the approach I mentioned. http://jsfiddle.net/ab5yn7eL/1/

Comment: @smerny Ah, good call. Yeah, I was still thinking 2 separate event handlers.